# Plot several parametric curves

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I'm trying to plot two parametric graphs as follows:

```
   alpha3[t_] := {Sin[2t]Cos[t],Sin[2t]Sin[t]}
   evoluta[t_] := alpha3[t]+(1/kappa[alpha3][t]) normal[alpha3][t]
   graph1 = ParametricPlot[alpha3[t]//Evaluate,{t,-2Pi,2Pi},PlotStyle->{{PlotRange -> 1}}]
   graph2 = ParametricPlot[evoluta[t]//Evaluate,{t,-2Pi,2Pi},PlotStyle->{{RGBColor[0.8,0.2,0.2],PlotRange ->1}}]
   Show[graph1,graph2]
```

The result obtained is:

[image]

I would like that the whole plot appears on the screen, however, PlotRange->All is not working for me?

How can I do so?

**Extra (code for drawing evolute)**

```
tangent[alpha_][t_]:=D[alpha[u],u]/Simplify[Factor[D[alpha[u],u].D[alpha[u],u]]]^(1/2) /. u->t
J:={{0,-1},{1,0}}
normal[alpha_][t_]:=J.tangent[alpha][t]
kappa[alpha_][t_]:=Det[{D[alpha[u],u],D[alpha[u],{u,2}]}]/
Simplify[D[alpha[u],u].D[alpha[u],u]]^(3/2)/.u->t
```

Comment: Try `ParametricPlot[{alpha3[t], evoluta[t]} // Evaluate, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {{}, Directive[RGBColor[0.8, 0.2, 0.2], Thick]}]`.

Comment: ok, even ParametricPlot[ {alpha3[t],evoluta[t]}//Evaluate,{t,-2 Pi,2 Pi}] works apparently

Comment: Yes; I added `PlotStyle` just to show how to change styles for a specific curve. Remember to use `Directive[]` if you want to apply more than one style (e.g. color and thickness at the same time).

Comment: You did not include the definitions of `kappa` or `normal`. Questions should include executable code.

Comment: @BobHanlon I added the missing details, thanks

Comment: I wonder, why  `Show[graph1, graph2, PlotRange -> All] `  shall not work. With MMA Version 8.0 it workes fine together with your other code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the OP has forgotten to include the sundry definitions, let me instead present a compact way to render a curve and its [evolute](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Evolute.html):

```
f[t_] := {Sin[2 t] Cos[t], Sin[2 t] Sin[t]};

{{kappa[t_]}, {tangent[t_], normal[t_]}} = FrenetSerretSystem[f[t], t];

ParametricPlot[{f[t], f[t] + normal[t]/kappa[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: quadrifolium and its evolute]